# How to pass event data with a call declared into tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've this element

```
<img onclick=zoomaImmagine(this) src="images/icon.png"/>
```

The problem is that i need to pass the event data too for retrieve the mouseX position. I tryied to write

```
onclick=zoomaImmagine(this,evt)
```

but the result is that it's undefined
Any solution?

Comment: try `zoomaImmagine(this,event)`

Comment: @harsha post this answer. It's right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
zoomaImmagine(this,event)
```

Since you were using evt,JavaScript was not able to determine what `evt` meant and hence, it was throwing the `undefined` error

Comment: ahh sorry, i knew that i should try to initialize event where i initialize the functiom, instead you mean to write "event" instead of "e" at the function call... so, doing that it's work!

Comment: @AnnaLica : Glad that it worked for you. If you are satisfied with the answer , you could mark it as the selected answer.